# Wcf inside sharepoint 2013 random authentication error

Tags: authentication, wcf, ntlm

I have a wcf web service deployed inside the isapi folder of a sharepoint 2013.

Sometimes the web service go down and an iisreset seems to solve the problem.

The error message complains about a 'ntlm' authentication against a 'NTLM' authentication.

However I always log with the same user so the authentication problem seems strange to me.

> Logs:
>   SPSecurityContext: Get trust client failed with exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69c3241e6f0468ca'...
>
> Application error when access /_vti_bin/FileSystem.svc, Error=Provider type not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090017)
>
> Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0
>
> SPRequest.PreInitServer: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrAbsoluteRequestUrl=...

Answer (score 0):

web.config change try :

```
<security mode="Transport">
<transport clientCredentialType="NTLM" />
</security>
```

OR in code try

```
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

Comment: I have no web.config in my wcf, sharepoint does all the work.